# How do I add a VIMVideoPlayerView to my view controller?

Tags: ios, vimeo-player, vimeo-ios

Maybe I'm just going about this the wrong way, but I'm trying to figure out how to add a VIMVideoPlayerView to my view controller through storyboard.

The documentation says "Create a new VIMVideoPlayerView instance or set up an @IBOutlet:" which as far as I understand means that I should be able to add it through the interface builder. But this object does not appear in the object library.

I'm pretty new to this, so I'm trying to figure out how to add a submodule object into my storyboard. I added VIMVideoPlayer using CocoaPods.

If this actually isn't possible, what is the proper way to setup a VIMVideoPlayer programically?

Answer (score 0):

Drag a view from object list and change set it class to **VIMVideoPlayerView**. Then you will be able to create IBOutlet for this Enter VIMVideo class name under class

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with Vimeo library but you need to drag and drop a `UIView` on the storyboard and set the class of this `UIView` to `VIMVideoPlayerView`

[image]